# Send $_SESSION contents

Tags: php, session, post, curl

I'm working on a survey script and at the end of the survey, I have all the data I need in the $_SESSION. What's the best way to POST the contents of $_SESSION I'm interested in to a handler on another server? If I can't POST (using cURL or so), what are my other options?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you would do it with curl:

```
<?php
//Server to POST data to
$url = 'http://foo.com/bar';
$postVars = '';

foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    $postVars .= urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value).'&';
}

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST      ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    ,$postVars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

If curl isn't available you could use fsockopen (http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php), but that will be a bit more work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a database to store the survey results. You can access the remote server's database with the right configuration.

Comment: The entire script is database-independent and I don't have a database available to use. Is it possible without a database?

Answer (score 0):

why you can't POST? Maybe you'll be unable to use cURL or other libraries but, unless you server is firewalled or the PHP configuration has this disabled, you can open a network stream and POST from your script manually, there is nothing exoteric about it. If you can use PECL HTTP extension, look at [this](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2010/Three-Ways-to-Make-a-POST-Request-from-PHP), else you'll find plenty of example of manually doing a simple POST request